# Using JSON to store dictionary data

Tags: android, json

I want to make a dictionary (An android app). Is it a good idea to store all the data for the dictionary(words,sentences,etc) in a JSON file?What are other better alternatives?

Comment: instead you should use a database like room[https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room]

Answer (score 0):

This depending on your app business logic and what are you will do with this data.

**For example:**

if you will make an offline dictionary so you have two options

1- save data in a local database

2- save data in JSON file or text file

**I prefer storing data in the local database so it will be easily searching and do any query in it**

note that your application size will increase as your data increase

and if you will make an online dictionary you need to store data in an online database
(your application size still fixed as your data increase